# How do I unlock bootloader and root LG Optimus Zone 3 (VS425PP)?

Tags: rooting, bootloader-lock

How do I unlock the bootloader on LG Optimus Zone 3 (VS425PP) in a simple, easy to follow steps?

Then how do I root the device and return to a fully functional cell phone that is stable and rooted? Can't get any help from using FlashFire, KingoRoot, SuperSU.

Comment: Verizon -> don't expect anything like that.

Comment: Verizon devices have locked bootloaders. Don't think this could be unlock-able.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unlock the bootloader on the LG Optimus Zone 3.

However, you can root the device using a system-wide root strategy -- thus avoiding the inevitable risk of modifying the boot image, KingoRoot is the best method -- however, you must be running an older firmware build such as vs425pp2.

To downgrade to vs425pp2, you will need a KDZ or TOT firmware package and LGUP Dev Edition.

Once the root is established, you may use SuperSU-Me Pro to substitute the KingoRoot binaries with SuperSU root binaries. Then you can use FlashFire to upgrade back to a more recent firmware build, maintaining root with the EverRoot feature.